# Creating signatures of a class in vim

Tags: vim

i have a file filled with this text:

```
class Baz
{
  void Test()
  {

  }

  int Sum (int)
  {

  }
}
```

and i want to create another buffer from that text like following:

```
interface IBaz
{
  void Test();
  int Sum (int);
}
```

how can i do that edit in vim. Any plugin or some strokes on keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file follows the exact pattern you posted, you can solve this with 4 commands:

```
:%s/^class\s*/interface I
:%s/^\s\+{\_[^}]*}//
:g/^\s*$/d
:%s/)\zs$/;
```

1. Change `class` to `interface I`
2. Delete indented blocks
3. Remove blank lines
4. Add `;` after ending `)`

If you need to use that in more than one file (though I recommend this even if you're going to use it once) copy and paste this text to a buffer then write it on a file, say `/tmp/cs`. Then, while focused on the buffer you want to change, run `:so /tmp/cs`.